# Lightweight email address regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using the following regular expression to test whether an email-address is valid:

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/
```

This works fine for most email-addressess execpt for one where an @-sign is being used in the last part of the email-address, for example: email@address.co@m will give a valid email-address result.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `^` to the start and `$` to the end:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

This makes sure that the string **must** start with the first match and **must** end with the last match.

`email@address.co@m` matched `email@address.co` as these weren't set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
    alert("Invalid Email Id");
    flag=1;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need

**Regex: `^[0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$`**

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tL3uJ4)

Why your regex passes is that it doesn't have start(`^`) and end(`$`) anchors.

You can [see here](http://regex101.com/r/rL5rQ1) what it matches.

Comment: @downvoter Please explain why so sudden a downvote. Did I miss anything ?